# Is it impossible for a deployed contract to call another contract, if it is not written in code within itself?

Tags: contract-development

Basically what I am doing is I am passing ownership of contract A to contract B.

The function below is only in contract A. I do not give contract B any code to call this function.

```
  function setOwner(address _owner) onlyOwner {
    pause();
    balances[owner] = initial_supply - public supply;
    owner = _owner;
    balances[owner] = public_supply;
  }
```

So I want to know, once I pass ownerhsip of A to B, is it impossible for it to change hands again? I want it to lock the ownership so I am hoping this is true! Thanks!

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, could you please mark it so other users know :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing stopping the `setOwner` function from being invoked again then it is possible to change the owner (but only by contract B if that's the new owner).

I'd suggest placing some code within the `setOwner` function so that it is only able to be executed once. For example:

```
bool isOwnerSet = false;
function setOwner(address _owner) onlyOwner {
    if(!isOwnerSet) {
        pause();
        balances[owner] = initial_supply - public supply;
        owner = _owner;
        balances[owner] = public_supply;
        isOwnerSet = true;
  }
}
```

This will mean that the new owner will not be able to invoke `setOwner` in the future.

Comment: So if Contract B is the owner, and contract B has no way to call setOwner, is it effectively locked forever that contract B is the owner?

Comment: If you want contract B to be the new owner and never change, then make sure that the `owner = contractBAddress`. Yes, contract B will be the owner forever if that is the case, provided there is no way to revert `isOwnerSet` back to false i.e. private variable without a setter.

Comment: @davekajpust fyi